# Unable to Deploy to Tomcat using Maven3 with Mail API

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-3

I am working on an application where we need to use java mail functionality. We have started using maven 3.x as out build tool.

Everything was working fine till Java Mail API has not been introduced. We are using Eclipse with M2Eclipse plugin but most of our deployment work is being done by maven Command line.

We have introduced following dependency in our pom.xml and I have verify that both mail.jar and activation.jar are in there respected folder structure.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

We tried the following command

```
> mvn clean
```

and then

```
>mvn tomcat:deploy
```

Though maven is showing that it has successfully deployed war on the tomcat but tomcat console showing that it is failing to deploy application and in other successful cases we are facing a strange issue, as we are using hibernate for persistance layer so on examing the folder structure it came out that the mapping file `.hbm` files are missing due to which Session factory is not creating and server is not able to startup.

Here is the snap shot of plugin entry

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <warFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</warFile>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>
                    <server>localhost</server>
                    <path>/blood_donor</path>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Could you specify Tomcat version. Is the artifact already deployed in the Tomcat when you try to deploy?

Answer (score 0):

From you procedure I see:

1. `mvn clean` - that deletes target directory with your build
2. `mvn tomcat:deploy` - should take the build (which was deleted with mvn clean) and deploy it on tomcat

There is no build phase. So use instead `mvn clean package tomcat:deploy`. If your application is already deployed in tomcat try `mvn clean package tomcat:redeploy`. For details check [plugin documentation](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/context-goals.html).

Which Tomcat version do you use?
According to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/tomcat-maven-plugin/ you use the version `1.1`. In the [plugin documentation](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/examples/deployment-tomcat7.html) you can find there that `Tomcat 7` is not supported in this version. For that you must upgrade to version `2.0`. See http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0-SNAPSHOT/

Probably yo